# jquery hover and adding class

Tags: jquery, hover, addclass

This sounds simple but i can't seem to make it work.

I'm trying to make my list have a scroll effect only when user hovers above it.

When I hover above the list, the classes don't change and the scroll bar doesnt appear.

I have the following css class and script

CSS

```
    .business_update_old{font-size:11px;max-height:300px}
    .no_scroll{overflow:hidden}
    .scroll{overflow:auto}
```

Script

```
    $('.business_update_old').hover(function(){
       $(this).removeClass("no_scroll");    
       $(this).addClass("scroll");
    });
```

PHP

```
    :
    :
    echo '<div class="business_update_old no_scroll">';
    echo '<ul class="business_updates_new"></ul>';
    :
    foreach(...
```

Be glad if anyone can provide any assistance here. Thanks. Appreciated

Comment: What is the question?  What part is not working?  Where's the code that restores the classes when you stop hovering?

Comment: Hi. Updated my qn. Problem lies where I'm not able to change the class when I hover above my div.

Comment: Oopps. Forgotten my $(document).ready. Thanks jfriend00 for reading

Comment: if it is solved, you may include your **own** answer here - which you can tick as correct ... so you provide some information for some other guy, who may have the same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```
$('.business_update_old').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('no_scroll').addClass('scroll');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('scroll').addClass('no_scroll');
    }
);​
```

When in doubt, [check the docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/td5P3/1/) shows it working.

You will, first, need to make sure that there is enough content to fill the 300px high div, like I have in the fiddle.

Also, to make sure the scroll bar doesn't stick around, you'll need to use this jQuery

```
$('.business_update_old').hover(
function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass("no_scroll")
    $this.addClass("scroll")
}, function() {
    $this.removeClass("scroll")
    $this.addClass("no_scroll");
});​
```

---

Alternatively, you can just do this with CSS, removing the need for jQuery totally.

If you set your CSS up like this

```
.business_update_old {
    font-size:11px;
    max-height:300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.business_update_old:hover {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Then it will work also. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/td5P3/2/) fiddle.

Comment: Why do this: `$this = $(this);`?